# Undefined columns selected error inside an R function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, rstudio, pca

Im trying to reproduce the example on the `statVisual` package documentation for the [PVCA](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statVisual/versions/1.1.8/topics/PVCA) function.

Here's the code:

```
library(pvca)


data(statVisual::esSim)
print(statVisual::esSim)

# expression data
dat = exprs(statVisual::esSim)
print(dim(dat))
print(dat[1:2,])

# create a fake Batch variable
statVisual::esSim$Batch=c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 10))
# phenotype data
pDat = pData(statVisual::esSim)
print(dim(pDat))
print(pDat[1:2,])


# feature data
fDat = fData(statVisual::esSim)
print(dim(fDat))
print(fDat[1:2,])


statVisual::statVisual(type = 'PVCA',
           clin_data = pData(statVisual::esSim), 
           clin_subjid = "sid", 
           gene_data = exprs(statVisual::esSim), 
           batch.factors = c("grp", "Batch"))

statVisual::PVCA( 
  clin_data = pData(statVisual::esSim), 
  clin_subjid = "sid", 
  gene_data = exprs(statVisual::esSim), 
  batch.factors = c("grp", "Batch"))
```

This is yelling the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(designCov, , batch.factors, drop = FALSE) :    undefined columns selected
```

I don't know what's going wrong, this is a documentation example. I would really thank if someone could point me in the right direction here.

Thank you very much in advance